# Post the data from React typescript to laravel using API, But it returned Null in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I created an API to add new records to the database table. Using React to POST the data to Laravel In JSON format, I sent the data to the Laravel POST method.

This is my React code

```
const data = await fetch(baseUrl + "/addnewlead", {
method: "post",  
mode: "cors", 
cache: "no-cache", 
credentials: "same-origin", 
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",
Authorization: `Bearer:`+token,   },    
body: JSON.stringify({
  value: order
}),
```

The output

```
{
"id": '1',
"first_name": "XXXX",
"last_name": "XXXX",
"email": "XXXX@yahoo.com",
"telephone1": "XXXXX",
"company_name": "XXX" }
```

Using Postman, I checked that the Laravel code worked fine. But when I execute on the webserver, it returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Code

export async function addOrder(order: any) {

```
const requestJson = JSON.stringify({
  first_name: order.first_name,
  last_name: order.last_name,
  email:order.email,
  telephone1:order.telephone1,
  company_name:order.company_name   });  
  const data = await fetch(baseUrl + "/addnewlead", {
  method: "post",  
  mode: "cors", 
  cache: "no-cache", 
  credentials: "same-origin", 
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",},    
  body: requestJson,   
  }).then((response)=>{
     if(response.ok){
     alert("Record added Successfully");
   }
   else {
      throw new Error('Server response wasn\'t OK');
   } });
     return data; 
    }
```

Laravel Controller code

```
public function addnewleaddata(Request $request) {  
$data = $request->all();
$lead = new Leads;
$lead->first_name = $data['first_name'];
$lead->last_name = $data['last_name'];
$lead->email = $data['email'];
$lead->telephone1 = $data['telephone1'];
$lead->company_name = $data['company_name'];
$lead->status = 'New';
$lead->save();
return response()->json("Add New data Successfully");
}
```